# Azure Mobile service Database clear

Tags: android, azure, mobile, service

I am working with an android application where I am implementing an azure offline syncing. I created a database as of MicroSoft azure tutorial. When I login with another user the application crashed. Working with same user like storing his data in to database works perfectly, but when new user comes to know the application crashed, this is happens because I have to clear all the database when a particular user logout, but I don't know how to do that.

When I login with my username and password I hit a login web service, on successful login I create a local Database for offline syncing. When the user logout and login again with different username and password, my app crash.
Because my previous DB's data is still there in local. Hence my app crash.

How I am creating the local DB

```
Map<String, ColumnDataType> medicalInfoTableDefinition = new HashMap<String, ColumnDataType>();
        medicalInfoTableDefinition.put("userId", ColumnDataType.String);
        medicalInfoTableDefinition.put("vitalId", ColumnDataType.String);
        medicalInfoTableDefinition.put("measurement", ColumnDataType.String);
        medicalInfoTableDefinition.put("measuredOn", ColumnDataType.String);
        medicalInfoTableDefinition.put("measuredAtLab", ColumnDataType.Boolean);
        medicalInfoTableDefinition.put("vital", ColumnDataType.Other);
        medicalInfoTableDefinition.put("id", ColumnDataType.String);
        medicalInfoTableDefinition.put("__version", ColumnDataType.String);
        medicalInfoTableDefinition.put("__deleted", ColumnDataType.Boolean);
        localStore.defineTable("MedicalInfo", medicalInfoTableDefinition);
```

Comment: Hello. So please deliver more information. You register new user first and after that yoy signing in with that user yes?

Comment: yes, the same user which is register can login, but another register user can't login.